# Sleep function in C

Tags: c, sleep, system-calls

I know this is a simple one, still  I'm too sleepy to figure it out. 
Can someone help me?

```
char buf1[] = "one second program started\n";
char buf2[] = "one second program end\n";

int main(void)
{
 write(1,buf1,100);
 sleep(1);
 write(1,buf2,100);
}
```

I need the first statement printed, then after a unit wait, the second statement to be printed. But, when I execute this, both the statements are printed, then a unit wait and the second statement is printed twice. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try to stay away from system calls like read/write as much as possible when writing portable C code. The standard library provides plenty of higher-level functions that are far more pleasant to work with.

Comment: Awesome! thanks everyone. Well, i know i should stay away from System Calls. But the whole point of this, is to use only system calls..from Man 2 page ONLY. I changed the 100 to the actual size and it worked fine. Does anyone have an idea on.. how I can read from a file upto the end of the LINE only? again only System Calls.

Comment: Sleepy? How's that relevant or helpful? Even so, how about getting rested and then attacking the problem again?

Comment: The kernel doesn't care about the content of the data; it doesn't even know it is text.  Line-based text processing is handled by the standard I/O functions in the C library.  If you don't want to use that then you can always do something similar in your own code: read large blocks of data into a buffer and look for newlines yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `100` to `strlen(buf1)` or `strlen(buf2)`.

Answer (score 5):

`write` does not care about C strings, it writes exactly as many bytes as you specified (if it can). In your case, it is reading past `buf1`'s end, which is undefined behavior.

Use `puts` instead if you want to print strings.

```
puts(buf1);
```

If for some reason you *have* to use `write`, provide the actual string length as the size argument.

Comment: The puts function may be more appropriate if a plain string is to be printed, as it cannot create format string bugs. printf(buf1) might be very tempting to an inexperienced C programmer. (Do remember that puts adds a trailing newline, though)

Comment: There's always `printf("%s", buf1)`